# How to disable spring security for specific url only via config?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I have a specific application URL - https://baseurl/contextroot. It is an Angular5 app packaged within a spring boot application. I want to enable spring security for all urls except https://baseurl/contextroot/path1.

My application does not have user login.

I tried something like below, based on results from search forums. The below code does not even load my application https://baseurl/contextroot and it returns 403.

Error:
(type=Forbidden, status=403).
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Build the request matcher for CSFR protection
        RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

            // Disable CSFR protection on the following urls:
            private AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = {  new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/path1")
            };

            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                // If the request match one url the CSFR protection will be disabled
                for (AntPathRequestMatcher rm : requestMatchers) {
                    if (rm.matches(request)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } // method matches

        }; // new RequestMatcher

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
         // Disable the csrf protection on some request matches
         .csrf()
         .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher);

        return;
    } // method configure
}
```

Also my application will be a child application, loaded in a iframe and I wanted to allow only certain urls to be load my application and I found option to add header writer but I could not get something like below to work.

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
        new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(Arrays.asList("allowed-website-1","allowed-website-2"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing like this.

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/contextroot/path1").permitAll();

    }
```

Comment: just to confirm, I do not need any csrf check for "/contextroot/path1". This accomplishes the same?

Comment: you wont need any csrf. It should work. You can add this line, in case of any error    http.csrf().disable();

Comment: I believe this will disable crsf checks. But I need CSRF enabled as part of our security requirement. I tried this and it validates csrf for "/contextroot/path1" as well and gives 403 error. "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found."